# OLS with multicollinear data and possible polynomial effects - what feature selection techniques would work?

Tags: cross-validation, least-squares, regression-coefficients, lasso, aic

I am new to regression modelling, have a dataset (vegetation health over time for ~250 sites) that I would like to model using OLS as a function of 5 continuous variables: light, pollution, humidity, temperature, and precipitation.

I'm particularly interested in the effect pollution has on vegetation health, but its variables are known to be smaller than the other 4, so I hope that by including the other variables in my model I can improve my estimate of the pollution's coefficient.

Looking at the dataset, I have identified several issues:

- **High multicollinearity** between all the variables (e.g. sunny days involve high temperatures, etc.), including between pollution and the other variables.
- **Possible polynomial effects** - according to laboratory studies, there are potential nonlinear relationships between these independent variables and the vegetation health. In the past these have usually been modelled as quadratic polynomials. However, other studies based on field measurements have yielded perfectly sensible results by fitting only linear variables.
- **Non-Gaussian distributions** - none of the variables are entirely Gaussian, even after I fit and apply a Box-Cox transformation using `scipy.stats.boxcox` in Python.

As polynomial terms can introduce further collinearity to the problem, I have decided to model each variable as a set of orthogonal polynomial terms, and to include interaction terms (e.g. "temperature * pollution") in my fit. But this means I have > 20 variables in my model, so to avoid overfitting I need to try simplifying the model through feature selection. I also want to automate this somehow over all ~250 subsets of data I have.

Based on my problem, I have the following questions that I've not been able to find answers to:

1. What feature selection technique is most robust to multicollinearity?
2. Can I throw all 20+ variables (including all polynomial and interaction terms) into a feature selection algorithm and assume a sensible answer will come out?
3. As I'm only interested in estimating the effect pollution has on vegetation health, does it necessarily matter if my feature selection returns an interaction term without one of the main variables? (e.g. selecting temperature * pollution but not temperature)? I want my fit to be useful in predicting future vegetation health, but am not necessarily interested in the other variables unless they impact pollution as well.
4. I've experimented with using LASSO on my dataset, using `sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV`. I fed the surviving variables into a normal OLS fit using `statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS` to further scrutinise the fit, and found that several terms that `LassoCV` had selected were insignificant ($p > 0.05$). Why were these variables chosen by LASSO, and would it still be defensible to include these in my final model to make predictions?
5. How alarmed should I be that none of my variables follow a Gaussian distribution? I would switch to using a GLS fit, but none of the supported distributions are perfect fits for my variables either.

Comment: Is this a public dataset by any chance?

Comment: @RyanVolpi: Not really. It's based on publicly available satellite and reanalysis data that I have collated together, gridded, and reprocessed.

Comment: For (5), what doesn't follow a Gaussian distribution, the raw data or the error term? We only care about the distribution of the error term in OLS, and even then it is for doing inference. The Gauss-Markov theorem gets you the unbiased estimate whether the error term is Gaussian or not, though you lose that unbiasedness when you do LASSO. GLS might be a good idea for you if you have varying variance of the error term, however.

Comment: @Dave: The raw data. I've not yet looked at the error terms or inspected the residuals. As far as I can tell, the variance of my data does not vary over time according to the Mann-Kendall test.

Comment: You don't care about the variance of your response variable or its distribution. You care about the error term, and even that might not be so important for prediction. What do you want to do with your model once you have it? Hypothesis test? Confidence intervals? Prediction?

Comment: @Dave: I'd like to look for spatiotemporal variation in the pollution term (whether autocorrelation in the residuals need to be addressed), and calculate confidence intervals. My eventual goal is to have something robust enough to look at projected vegetation damage due to pollution & other conditions in the future.